# Send radio buttons values to parent component - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button, output

I have a form with radio buttons from Angular Material inside a parent component, I need to get the values of the radio buttons, send them to the parent component and then show a different content depending of the radio button selected. I know that I need to use @output to send data to the parent component but my code is not working. Any ideas?

[CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esrgod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.ts)

Comment: The code is working fine for me. I can see an alert with the option I selected after I click submit

Answer (score 2):

You have to `emit` from the child component the value from your form like:

```
@Output() formSubmitted = new EventEmitter<string>();

  submit(): void {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.formSubmitted.emit(this.form.value.seasonsForm!);
  }
```

And retrieve the value from the parent component like this:

##### HTML

```
  <app-child (formSubmitted)="editSeasonVisibility($event)"></app-child>
```

##### TS

```
  editSeasonVisibility(seasonSelected: string) {
    // Your logic to switch content
    console.log(`Selected season from parent`, seasonSelected);
  }
```

You can also see the official document [Sharing data between child and parent directives and components](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)